# The same (int)doubles round up and down in Java

Tags: java, int, double, rounding, mouselistener

I'm having the weirdest problem with my game in java. :|

I can get around it, so I will be able to continue on this game without a solution, but I just thought it was really weird.

It's a 2D Minecraft-ish (I know, I know, it's just for practice) game, and I'm trying to destroy blocks by clicking them, which is working, but not as expected.

```
mX = (x * blockWidth - screenWidth * blockWidth / 2 + blockWidth / 2 + e.getX()) / blockWidth;
mY = y - screenHeight / 2 + .5 + e.getY() / blockHeight;
```

These two lines should define the x and y coordinates of the block the mouse is currently hovering over. Filling in the same numbers will result in the same answer as the second formula is a shorter version of the first. However, the second one does not work, clicking a block in the upper half section will result in breaking the block above it. The only reason I can think of is that, in the mouseClicked() method, the (int) (which is required as you can't click on half coordinates) rounds the first one up and the second one down because of the .5 in it. I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking you. :)

Does anyone know what the cause of this might be? I prefer not to use the upper formula because I want it to be much simpler.

Comment: What are the variable types? All doubles?

Comment: Java is doing some hidden casts. Depending on which variable is a double or an int, you might get unexpected results because some double values have been casted to int.
I would make sure all your variables are doubles.

Comment: Also, do not forget that floating points also have representation limitations, that can affect computation and computation results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is doing some hidden casts. Depending on which variable is a double or an int, you might get unexpected results because some double values have been casted to ints. I would make sure all your variables are doubles.

Also, do not forget that floating points also have representation limitations, that can affect computation and computation results.

If you want to round your value, you can use:

`Math.round(2.7);`

if you want to "round up", you can use:

`Math.ceil(2.7);`

if you want to "round down", you can use:

`Math.floor(2.7);`

Comment: Only mX, x, mY and y are doubles, the other ones are ints. I tried rounding them but it didn't work. So I'll just use the long formula. Thank you for explaining! :)

Comment: To make round(), ceil(), floor()  shorter you can static import them, using:

`import static java.lang.Math.*;`

If this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer.